# How to kill a process in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm the maintainer of grunt-sinatra(a name which i should change, but thats not the topic of this conversation) and in order to test a new feature, I want to launch the rack server and then kill it. that test was passing before, now it isn't.

The problem is that i have tried every option i have read about in the internet and none work.
I have pushed the troubling codebase to [this branch](https://github.com/vjustov/grunt-sinatra/tree/sinatra-theinmortal) and i'd love you forever if you can help me solve the issue (and explain the reason why it didn't work)

Comment: Could you give us an even more isolated example of what you have tried? It's going to be a lot easier than trying to dig through code on a branch.

Comment: I'll try to isolate the problem further. I'll update the post when i do it.